# how can I make a loop through parsing

Tags: python

I have a code which tries to get data from Desktop , then parse to a web, translate and paste the translated as output

```
import urllib,urllib2

with open('/path to the data/data.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
with open('/path to the output/output.txt') as ff:

url = 'http://www.uniprot.org/mapping/'

print "From To"
for genename_id in lines:
    params = {
    'from':'ACC+ID',
    'to':'GENENAME',
    'format':'tab',
    'query':genename_id
    }

    data = urllib.urlencode(params)
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    contact = "" # Please set your email address here.
    request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Python %s' % contact)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    page = response.read(200000)
    ff.write(page.splitlines()[1])
```

The data.txt is below

```
G5E8R3     
Q99MR6-3    
D3YVD3     
G3UZM2     
Q1MWP8     
D3Z2K3     
Q8BZM2     
P09103     
Q9JJG0-3    
Q9R0Q6     
Q3UY11     
Q8C3Z4     
Q3UVN6     
Q80U36     
Q9R1A1
```

I have trying to do two things

1- I want to be able to convert the data and if it does not exist, I want to have a empty space in from of the one that does not exist

so a desire output like this

```
From       To 
G5E8R3     Pcx
Q99MR6-3    
D3YVD3     Eno2
G3UZM2     Rhoj
Q1MWP8     Ehd4
D3Z2K3     Actg2
Q8BZM2     Anks1b
P09103     P4hb
Q9JJG0-3    
Q9R0Q6     Arpc1a
Q3UY11     Scamp1
Q8C3Z4     Prkar1a
Q3UVN6     Abi2
Q80U36     Dync1h1
Q9R1A1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the way you write to `output.txt`

1. You are not opening it with a `write` permission, which will lead to an `IOError` exception.
2. There is an assumption that the response page will contain 2 lines of output every time. You should have tested it before, by printing the response, and see that there is only one line in case the conversion fails. Therefor, you need to add a test to check it.

In conclusion, consider the next code:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

with open('/path/to/data.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
with open('/path/to/output.txt', 'w') as ff:
    url = 'http://www.uniprot.org/mapping/'

    ff.write("From\tTo\n")
    for genename_id in lines:
        params = {
            'from': 'ACC+ID',
            'to': 'GENENAME',
            'format': 'tab',
            'query': genename_id
        }
        data = urllib.urlencode(params)
        request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
        contact = "some@email.addrs"
        request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Python %s' % contact)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        page = response.read()
        ff.write('%s\n' % (page.splitlines()[1] if len(page.splitlines()) > 1 else genename_id))
```

Notice:

- I used `'w'` as a second parameter to the `open` function of the `output.txt` file, so I'll have write permission to it. Read about `open` function [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).
- I checked the response's lines length and printed the desired data.
- I removed the parameter for `response.read`.
- I changed the `print "From To"` you wrote to `ff.write("From\tTo\n")` so it will be in `output.txt` file.

Comment: I liked and accepted your answer. thanks what if I want to put NA instead the blank , do you know how I can do that ?

Comment: If you meant to have something like `Q99MR6-3 NA` just add `+ ' NA'` after `else genename_id` and before the parenthesis like this: `else genename_id + ' NA'))`.